# import text data having spaces using pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, regex-negation

I would like to import a text file using pandas.read_csv:

```
1541783101     8901951488  file.log             12345  123456
1541783401     21872967680  other file.log       23456     123
1541783701     3  third file.log 23456     123
```

The difficulty here is that the columns are separated by one or more spaces, but there is one column that contains a file name having spaces. So I can't use `sep=r"\s+"` to identify the columns as that would fail at the first file name having a space. The file format does not have a fixed column width.

However each file name ends with ".log". I could write separate regular expressions matching each column. Is it possible to use these to identify the columns to import? Or is it possible to write a separator regular expression that selects all characters NOT matching any of the column matching regular expressions?

Comment: use delimeter parameter in `read_csv`?

Comment: Did you double check that in the original data there is not `'\t'` used as separator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer for updated question -**

Here's the code which will not fail whatever the data width may be. You can modify it as per your needs.

```
df = pd.read_table('file.txt', header=None)

# Replacing uneven spaces with single space
df = df[0].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.split()))

# An empty dataframe to hold the output
out = pd.DataFrame(np.NaN, index=df.index, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'])

n_cols = 5      # number of columns
for i in range(n_cols-2):
    # 0 1
    if i == 0 or i == 1:
        out.iloc[:, i] = df.str.partition(' ').iloc[:,0]
        df = df.str.partition(' ').iloc[:,2]
    else:
        out.iloc[:, 4] = df.str.rpartition(' ').iloc[:,2]
        df = df.str.rpartition(' ').iloc[:,0]
        out.iloc[:,3] = df.str.rpartition(' ').iloc[:,2]
        out.iloc[:,2] = df.str.rpartition(' ').iloc[:,0]

print(out)

+---+------------+-------------+----------------+-------+--------+
|   |    col1    |      col2   |       col3     |   col4 |   col5 |
+---+------------+-------------+----------------+-------+--------+
| 0 | 1541783101 |  8901951488 | file.log       | 12345 | 123456 |
| 1 | 1541783401 | 21872967680 | other file.log | 23456 |    123 |
| 2 | 1541783701 |           3 | third file.log | 23456 |    123 |
+---+------------+-------------+----------------+-------+--------+
```

*Note - The code is hardcoded for 5 columns. It can be generalized too.*

**Previous answer -**

Use `pd.read_fwf()` to read files with fixed-width.

In your case:

```
pd.read_fwf('file.txt', header=None)

+---+----------+-----+-------------------+-------+--------+
|   |    0     |  1  |         2         |   3   |   4    |
+---+----------+-----+-------------------+-------+--------+
| 0 | 20181201 |   3 | file.log          | 12345 | 123456 |
| 1 | 20181201 |  12 | otherfile.log     | 23456 |    123 |
| 2 | 20181201 | 200 | odd file name.log | 23456 |    123 |
+---+----------+-----+-------------------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Could work here - however, the sample dataset doesn't look that _fixed_...

Comment: The solution is built using dataset provided by OP.

Comment: I know - as I said _could_ work, because it works with those three lines. But they're not really nice fixed width, so it's not known what structure will have some other lines in the data files we do not see here.

Comment: Agree. Let OP check, if any modification is needed, I'll do.

Comment: the original file format is in fact not fixed. It has file sizees, time stamps, checksums etc. per line.

Comment: `read_fwf` does in fact read the small example file, even if I make it even more non-fixed width. That is surprising, I did not expect that. Unfortunately the function fails on the real file as it is much more non-fixed width.

Comment: Can you elaborate, when you say the function fails on real file. Is it throwing an error or are you able to read the file but with mismatched column values?

Comment: I have edited the original file to show where it fails with `read_fwf`.